# how to solve error of log() produces NaNs in r

Tags: r

I am trying to do a monte carlo simulation study on my user-defined distribution and I had modified my `R` code from another one I saw in an article. My `R` codes are given below;

```
library(rootSolve)
library(Matrix)
library(bbmle)

alpha=4
beta=0.3
rho=2
lambda=0.5
theta=0.2

samp=1000
par1=c(alpha,beta,rho,lambda,theta)

####Define BXIIWG quantile
BXIIWG_quantile=function(alpha,beta,rho,lambda,theta,u){
  f=function(x){
  beta*x^alpha+lambda*log(1+x^rho)+log(1-u)
  }
  x=uniroot(f,c(0,100),tol=0.0001)$root
  return(x)
}

####Define BXIIWG log-likelihood
BXIIWG_neglogl=function(alpha,beta,rho,lambda,theta){
  -sum(log(alpha*beta*x^(alpha-1)*(1+x^rho)+rho*lambda*x^(rho-1)))+(lambda+1)*sum(log(1+x^rho))-n*log(1-theta)+beta*sum(x^alpha)+2*sum(log(1-theta*(1+x^rho)^(-lambda)*exp(-beta*x^alpha)))
}

####Define simulation process of BXIIWG
BXIIWG_simulation=function(size=c(25,50,100,200,400,800),samp,par1){
Mean=vector()
RMSE=vector()
Bias=vector()
for (iter_size in 1:length(size)){
coef1=matrix(NA,samp,5)
colnames(coef1)=c('alpha','beta','rho','lambda','theta')
for (nsamp in 1:samp){
tryCatch(
{
x1_BXIIWG=NULL
q=runif(size[iter_size],0,1)
x1=sapply(q,BXIIWG_quantile,
alpha=par1[1],beta=par1[2],rho=par1[3],lambda=par1[4],theta=par1[5])
###BXIIWG for x1
x1_BXIIWG<-mle2(BXIIWG_neglogl,
start=list(alpha=par1[1],beta=par1[2],rho=par1[3],lambda=par1[4],theta=par1[5]),
method="L-BFGS-B",data=list(x=x1),
lower=c(alpha=0,beta=0,rho=0,lambda=0,theta=0),
upper=c(alpha=Inf,beta=Inf,rho=Inf,lambda=Inf,theta=1),use.ginv=TRUE)
coef[nsamp,]=coef(x1_BXIIWG)
},error=function(e){}
)
}
Mean[length(size)*(0:4)+iter_size]=apply(coef1,2,mean,na.rm=TRUE)
RMSE[length(size)*(0:4)+iter_size]=apply((coef1-matrix(rep(par1,nsamp),
ncol=5,byrow=T))^2,2,function(x){sqrt(mean(x,na.rm=TRUE))})
  }
Bias-as.vector(sapply(1:5,function(x){Bias[(length(size)*(x-1)+1):
(length(size)*x)]=Mean[(length(size)*(x-1)+1):(length(size)*x)]-par1[x]}))
samplesize=as.vector(t(mapply(rep,size,5)))
return(cbind(samplesize,Mean,RMSE,Bias))
}
BXIIWGsim1<-BXIIWG_simulation(25,1000,par1)
Mean1<-BXIIWGsim1$Mean
RMSE1<-BXIIWGsim1$RMSE
Bias1<-BXIIWGsim1$Bias
```

When I run these codes, I obtained the following errors;

(1) `In log(1 - theta) : NaNs produced`

(2) `In log(1 - theta * (1 + x^rho)^(-lambda) * exp(-beta *  ... : NaNs produced`

and

(3) `No values of Mean,RMSE and Bias are displayed in console`

Please, I need help in solving these problems. Thank you.

Comment: `log(x)` will produce `NaN` any time `x` is less than zero. For example, if `theta > `, then `1 - theta < 0` and an error will be thrown. So, you have to think about what the restrictions on your parameter values are.

Answer (score 4):

Hi for `log(x)` produced NaN because of negative values.
suppose: `x = c(1,2,3,-4,-5)`
`log(x)` : `NaN`s produced

**Solution:**
 1. Need to Recheck on Dataset.
 2. If a few negative entries, then try to remove the observations [again depends on case to the case].
 3. use `abs()` : `abs(x)` : Ans. `1,2,3,4,5`.

Answer (score 0):

There's another easier solution, try to use `log1p()` (it computes *log(1+x)*).